# Regarding Spherical Gaussian Latent Space

Tags: autoencoders, latent-variable

I am currently reading paper on Variational Autoencoders by Dr. Kingma and Dr. Welling, and am having a few confusions.

[image]

**Question 1**: What is a spherical Gaussian latent space? How do we interpret it

**Question 2**: In equation 1.15, does the Roman I in standard deviation mean 1 or does it have a different meaning?

Could anyone please provide me some information on these?

Answer (score 1):

1. A spherical gaussian distribution is a multivariate normal distribution that has diagonal covariance *and* equal variances in all directions. A "spherical gaussian latent space" means that the latent space is a random variable with a spherical gaussian distribution.
2. $I$ is the [identity matrix.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix)

Comment: Thank you @Sycorax! I have added a confusion in the description. It would be great if you could please help me understand it.

Comment: Sycorax answered the question you posted. If you have another, please post it as a separate question instead of editing it into the previous one. If you take advantage of the opportunity to do that, I encourage you to specify where the newly added figures are taken from. They’re not comparable to each other.

Comment: @Curious Arya is correct — if you have a follow-up question, you should ask a new question

Comment: Sure, will add a new question. Thanks! Edit removed.